# (Swift) How to parse JSON response that sometimes contains a certain field?

Tags: json, swift, alamofire

I am trying to parse a JSON response that sometimes contains a field 'state' and sometimes does not. For example:

```
{
country: "US", 
lat: 69, 
lon: 69, 
name: "CityName",
state: "StateName"
}
```

vs.

```
{
country: "US", 
lat: 69, 
lon: 69, 
name: "CityName"
}
```

I am using Alamofire to parse it as such, but of course run into errors when the json response does not contain the 'state' field.

```
      AF.request("API.COM").responseData(completionHandler: { response in
            guard let data = response.data else { return }
            let responses = try! JSONDecoder().decode([apiResponse].self, from: data)
            print(responses as Any)
            self.dispatchGroup.leave()
        })
```

Where:

```
struct apiResponse: Decodable {
    var country: String
    var lat: Float
    var lon: Float
    var name: String
    var state: String
}
```

I would like to get a struct for each object in the response, whether or not it contains the 'state' field. What is the best way to do this? I tried using some do/catch logic to catch an error when parsing an object and then try to parse it with a decodable struct that didnt have the state field, but that didnt work out for me. Thank you so much in advance for any help.

Comment: You can directly decode your models using `responseDecodable(of: [APIResponse.self])`. Type renamed `APIResponse` to match Swift's naming guidelines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use an `Optional` for the optional property, that's what they're intended for. I.e,

```
var state: String?
```

Also, a couple of unrelated hints:

- you can likely change all the `var`s in your struct to `let`s
- rename it as `ApiResponse` (capital A) - types in Swift
  usually start with capital letters.
- look into using `URLSession` and `Codable` instead of adding thousands and thousands of lines of code from an external library.

Answer (score 2):

change

```
struct apiResponse: Decodable {
    var country: String
    var lat: Float
    var lon: Float
    var name: String
    var state: String
}
```

as

```
struct apiResponse: Decodable {
    var country: String
    var lat: Float
    var lon: Float
    var name: String
    var state: String?
}
```

and you can check state as

```
if let _ = model.state {
}
```